# ExtentReports Cucumber Report Parallel Execution with TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber-java, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I am running some Selenium tests via SauceLabs and my test framework is generating a report using the ExtentCucumberAdapter4 plugin.

I am running each of my Cucumber scenarios in parallel on separate threads, which are running as expected. However, when the report is generated by ExtentReports, it has each scenario run by a thread as an individual feature, see screenshot below.

[image]

Here's my feature file

```
@FeatureOne
Feature: Feature 1
Example Feature 


  Scenario: Attempting to login with invalid user
    Given I am at the login screen
    And I enter invalid user crendtials
    Then I should not be logged in


  Scenario: Logging in with valid user
    Given I am at the login screen
    And I enter valid user credentials 
    Then I should be logged in
```

and my test runner class:

```
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "features",
        tags = { "@FeatureOne" },
        glue = {"stepdefs"},
        plugin = {
                "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"
        }
)
public class TestNGCucumberRunner {

    private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpClass() {
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
    }

    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideScenarios();
    }

    @Test(description = "Cucumber Scenarios", dataProvider = "scenarios")
    public void feature(PickleEventWrapper pickleEvent, CucumberFeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) throws Throwable {
        testNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(pickleEvent.getPickleEvent());
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() {
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }
}
```

I'm expecting both the scenarios in Feature 1 to be under the same 'Feature 1' title in the report, but they appear as 2 of the same feature.

It seems that each running thread just adds what ever scenario it runs to the list of features. Does ExtentReport have any support for preventing this?

Comment: What is the version of your cucumber & extent adapter? I had read about the same issue on older versions of the adapter.

Comment: @sureshmani cucumber 4.2.0 and extent cucumber adaptor 1.0.5 - was getting errors when updating any of these

Comment: The fix is on version# 1.0.7 if you can upgrade to.